# How to navigate nested HABTM relationships?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, has-and-belongs-to-many

In my application:

- `User` has_and_belongs_to_many `Events`
- `Video` has_and_belongs_to_many `Events`

So a user may own multiple events, each of which has many videos, and the user accordingly owns the combined total of those events' videos.

Given a `user`, how can I obtain their `videos`?

I'm currently using this cumbersome workaround:

```
@events = @user.events
@videos = []
@events.map do |event|
  event.videos.map do |video|
    @videos.push(video)
  end
end
```

Is there a better and more efficient way to obtain that user's videos? As you can maybe tell I'm a Rails noob...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try setting up a "through" association:

```
class User
  has_and_belongs_to_many :events
  has_many :videos, :through => :events
```

you should now be able to:

```
user.videos
```

Heaps more detail on associations in the really-you-should-read-them-all Rails guides: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html
:)

---

Other random notes (mainly because you have self-described as a noob, and I taught this stuff for a while) ;)

1) you probably don't need the `@` in front of your rails variable names... you only need to call a variable `@something` if you are in the controller, and passing the variable to the view... otherwise you can just call it `something`

2) you really only need to use `map` if you're actually doing something the with end result eg:

```
other_numbers = [1,2,3].map {|num| num + 1 }
```

if you're not going to assign the result of map to something... then it's generally better to just use `each` eg:

```
events.each do |event|
  ...
```

3) in your loop, you grab an array `event.videos` then add each video individually to another array with `@videos.push`, but you can just add arrays together eg:

```
@videos = []
events.each do |event|
  @videos += event.videos
end
```

Comment: Many thanks. I love it when I get a response so quickly that StackOverflow won't actually let me accept it yet :)